# Combine Timer - setting timer

Tags: swiftui, timer, combine

I'm not very familiar with Combine's `Timer.publish(every:, on: , in: )`. Essentially I'm looking to run a timer to call a func in my `ObservableObject` class. Is there a better way of doing this, not sure if I'm doing so correctly or if there's a cleaner way of doing the same.

```swift
class Example : ObservableObject {
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    @Published var somedate: Date = Date()
    
    init() {
        cancellable = Timer
            .publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .sink(receiveValue: { _ in
                self.update()
            })
    }
    
    func update() {
        let publisher =  Date()
        Just(publisher)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            }, receiveValue: { date in
                self.somedate = date
                print(self.somedate)
            }).store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

The output seems correct.

```
2021-08-10 22:25:24 +0000
2021-08-10 22:25:25 +0000
2021-08-10 22:25:26 +0000
2021-08-10 22:25:27 +0000
2021-08-10 22:25:28 +0000
2021-08-10 22:25:29 +0000
2021-08-10 22:25:30 +0000
2021-08-10 22:25:31 +0000
2021-08-10 22:25:32 +0000
2021-08-10 22:25:33 +0000
2021-08-10 22:25:34 +0000
2021-08-10 22:25:35 +0000
2021-08-10 22:25:36 +0000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can significantly reduce complexity in your `update` function. There's no need to create a new publisher with `Just` to get the date. Plus, you can already get that in your initial `sink`:

```
class Example : ObservableObject {
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    @Published var somedate: Date = Date()
    
    init() {
        cancellable = Timer
            .publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] value in
                self?.update(date: value)
            })
    }
    
    func update(date: Date) {
        self.somedate = date
        print(self.somedate)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but in my real data it’s a lot more complex with Publishers.Zip but that gives me a good idea

Comment: @jnpdx did answer the question asked, so you should really accept his answer.

Comment: @Yrb, I wasn’t able to at that moment and planned on doing so, don’t appreciate the comment